# Hartl Chapter 7 Issue: No DRb server is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, spork

Here's the code I get when I'm running the `bundle exec rspec spec/.`

I pretty much copy-pasted everything Hartl told me to do, but I can't even get a red test off of this. In my gemfile, I added the `factory_girls_rails v. 4.2.1` gem, but I noticed there was already a default `factory_girls gem 4.2.0` in there. Is that the conflict?

---

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/zipper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.0.0/lib/selenium-webdriver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/nemo/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /home/nemo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 0):

`No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead` this messages appears because Spork server is not running, check [this thread](http://www.ruby-software.com/2012/05/18/no-drb-server-running-running-in-local-process-insead/) its about the error you got when you try to run `rspec spec` , also check [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork?view=asciicast) by Ryan Bates about spork

Comment: So, after struggling with this for a few days and combinations of search queries, I finally found the solution, which was a need to update the selenium-webdriver. Here's a quote from the answer I found: "I needed to update gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'to gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.35.1' and the problem all goes away." I'm sure somebody will run into this problem at some point.